# How to pass scalar parameters in EF6 raw sql function?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, sqlclient

I am adding scalar parameters in my SQLquery, but whenever the query executes I am getting an exception for the follwoing piece of code:

```cs
IEnumerable<ICRDocumentComplete> results = saturnContext
                .Set<ICRDocumentComplete>()
                .SqlQuery(query,
                    new SqlParameter("@StartDate", startDate),
                    new SqlParameter("@EndDate", endDate.AddDays(1)),
                    new SqlParameter("@SubmissionId", submissionId));
```

I have my query saved inside the `query` variable. I am getting a null reference, but I am assuming it is just because I didn't add the scalar variables correctly. Can someone shed some light on this matter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that `saturnContext`, `query`, `endDate` is not null at the time of execution.